# numba and variables defined in a closure

Tags: python, numba

I need to create a few `numba` functions which are parametrized by a dictionary. This dictionary is in the namespace of the factory function and I want to use it in the actual function.
The problem is that I get a NotImplemented error, is there a solution or even just a workaround to this problem?

I have simplified my code to this example:

The target cut function takes:

- a selector which decides which of the ranges in the dictionary it should use (`series`)
- a value to compare to the range which is in the dictionary (in the real application I have about a dozen of those ranges)

```py
from numba.core import types
from numba.typed import Dict

dict_ranges = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.int64,
    value_type=types.Tuple((types.float64, types.float64))
    )

dict_ranges[3] = (1, 3)

def MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges):
    def cut(series, value):
        return dict_ranges[series][0] < value < dict_ranges[series][1]
    return cut

MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges)(3,2)
True
```

In pure Python it works fine. With `numba`:

```
njit(MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges))(3,2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NumbaNotImplementedError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [107], line 1
----> 1 njit(MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges))(3,2)

File ~/micromamba/envs/root/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File ~/micromamba/envs/root/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

NumbaNotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
<numba.core.base.OverloadSelector object at 0x7f8c054fefd0>, (DictType[int64,UniTuple(float64 x 2)]<iv=None>,)
During: lowering "$2load_deref.0 = freevar(dict_ranges: {3: (1.0, 3.0)})" at /tmp/ipykernel_2259/3022317309.py (3)
```

In the simple case where the parameter is a simple type, this works fine:

```py
def MB_cut_factory(limit):
    def cut(value):
        return value < limit
    return cut

MB_cut_factory(4)(3)

njit(MB_cut_factory(4))(3)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot return a function in a compiled function. This is called a closure and this is complex to implement, especially in this context (the closure needs to keep a context of the parent function in a safe way)

Comment: well, if I just need to pass a simple type, this works fine, probably because it is passed by copy instead of by reference? I edited the question and added example with simple type.

Comment: In this case the question is why you really want to do this? If this would be working, it is just about compiling the dict natively in your code instead of just passing it to the function at runtime. Even if this would implemented, it wouldn't be possible to change the dict without recompilation?

Comment: I don't need to change the dict. Not sure what you mean compiling the dict natively.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that works for my case, but uses `exec`.

```py
def MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges):
    exec("def cut(series, value):\n    dict_ranges=" +\
         dict_ranges.__str__() +\
        "\n    return dict_ranges[series][0] < value < dict_ranges[series][1]", globals())
    return cut

MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges)(3,2)
True
njit(MB_cut_factory(dict_ranges))(3,2)
True
```

If someone has a less embarrassing solution to this problem, please!